# SSH - Diffie-Hellman; prime & g exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman, ssh

The Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm can be used with SSH.

But how does SSH exchange the `large safe prime p` and the `generator for a subgroup of GF(p) g`?
According to RFC 4253 the first steps are to send `e` & `f` which are calculated depending via:

```
 e = g^x mod p
 f = g^y mod p
```

Now `x` & `y` are randomly generated but how do both parties come to the same values of `g` and `p`? There seems to be no exchange happening of them.

Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: See [section 6.5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-6.5), there are the links for those. part of the protocol the DHKE parameters are exchanged, too.

Comment: Does [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87890/555) answer the question?

Comment: @kelalaka ahhh thanks didn't know that p and g are just defined.

Comment: @fgrieu thanks for the link to the indepth reply this solved it